# how to run a thread for a specific time in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, handler, java-threads

I am using a thread to run my database connection checking
I want this thread to run for a specific time ,
I tried using countdown Timer class ,but that didn't ,work any help please.

Comment: if you have a specific time you must use the `AlarmManger` you can schedule your check

Comment: I believe that AlarmManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) is not exactly what the op wants to achieve. As explained in the official documentation "The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService) and do something like this:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new DatabaseConnection());

        try {
            future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            ...
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            ...
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // do something in case of timeout
            future.cancel(true);
        }

        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}

class DatabaseConnection implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            // Perform your task here, e.g. connect to your database
        }
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

This way you perform a task on another thread with any timeout you want. In the above code snippet a timeout of three seconds is set.